# Weird characters in Serial Monitor and not functioning ESP8266 ESP-12e

Tags: serial, esp8266, ide

I did a bit of playing with my new ESP-12e, but suddenly it kind of fails on me. It gives me some weird looks it didn't give me (as much) before.

[image]

**This is what the Serial Monitor prints when I try to run a very simple sketch.** When I restart the module, it just adds some more of these chars.
**The following is the code for that:**

```
const int statusLED = 16;

void setup() {
  pinMode(statusLED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(statusLED, HIGH);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.write("The ESP-12e has started.");
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(statusLED, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(statusLED, HIGH);
}
```

This doesn't even involve the WIFI...

**These are my board settings:**
*Board: Generic ESP8266 Module

Flash mode: QIO

Flash frequency: 40MHz

CPU frequency: 80MHz

Flash size: 4M (3M SPIFFS)

Upload speed: 115200*

**And finally, if it might help, how I connected the module:**
[image]
All connections are solid, so that shouldn't be a problem. *The connection board has GPIO15 printed on it twice, but the one I connected to the LED is actually GPIO16.* I noticed that the onboard LED of the ESP-12e doesn't light on anymore.

I use the CP2102 USB to UART module.

Thanks!
Rogier

Comment: It seems like maybe the firmware itself is crashing. Have you tried reflashing the device a couple of times?

Comment: The output doesn't appear to be able to have come from your code. Are the states of GPIO[0,2,15] appropriate for booting, at boot time? For running from flash, at run time?

Comment: wow, a negative for that?  Problem isn't even solved yet. rough crowd.

Comment: Yes, the GPIO pins should be connected the right way. Also, I am able to upload to the flash memory.

Comment: Yeah, weird. I don't know who would do that. I will try to flash new firmware and get back to you! Thanks for your help!

Comment: you're welcome -- my ESP8266's have been super finicky, easy to get a bad flash on em

Comment: `I noticed that the onboard LED of the ESP-12e doesn't light on anymore` - looking at the pictures, I hope the power coming in on the barely visible orange wire is 3.3v

Comment: Yes, that is 3.3v input from a regulator. It also should have enough power (2A).

Comment: Hi @Malachi. It's been a while, and a struggle. I just can't get it to work! The new firmware was flashed no problem (kind of), but it just won't run my sketches, nor do the default AT commands work. I think it might just be broken somehow, so I have ordered a couple of new ESP-12Fs. Hope they all keep working.

Comment: Sorry to hear this.  I'm a little surprised to hear you mention AT commands, after flashing custom firmware I would not expect any AT commands to work.  One note: not necessarily gonna solve your problem, but get a genuine FTDI based setup - those CPxxx suckers have always added a layer of problems for me.

Comment: I have downloaded the firmware from the Espressif website, so it wasn't custom. What custom firmwares are there to try?j

Comment: For example your original posted sketch would constitute a custom firmware.  If you're using the ESP8266_AT firmware from the site, then yes I would expect AT commands to work (although I have never actually flashed that firmware before =)

Comment: Ah. OK! No the custom firmwares don't work either. Although they do upload without an error.

Comment: You should be seeing a blue LED flash when you power it on at least.  If not seeing that then I'd say power delivery or a broken ESP8266.  I use this to program mine: http://www.ebay.com/itm/252225272540

Comment: The blue LED flashes when I turn it on. I'll see if the new modules work.

Comment: OK that's good news - there's hope!  Is it possible for you to upload a youtube of the flashing process?  I get a lot of clues about how successful my flash is from how the lights blink. (hopefully your CP20xx has some lights... =)

Comment: A schematic is way more informative than those two photos. I really doesn't see how things are connected and can't check your circuit. (Not that I actually can, but someone else maybe).

Comment: NccWarp9 is right, e.g.: void setup() { Serial.begin(115200); you have to select 115200 in your baud serial monitor option. it works also for me (nodemcu 1.0)

Answer (score 2):

Check what baud rate is serial window displaying. It should be the same as defined in your code.

Comment: Thanks. But that's the same. I have tried other baud rates, but that doesn't change it.